# Dealing with multiple subprocesses writing to stdout in python

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, multiprocess

I have multiple subprocesses (opened with `subprocess.Popen`) continuously writing lots of short lines to stdout (several MB/s).
Sometimes, I guess when two subprocesses write at the exact same time to stdout, the output in stdout is an unreadable line.

For example, subprocess 1 writes AAAA, subprocess 2 write BBBB and stdout would sometimes show AABABABB instead of distinct AAAA and BBBB.

How to catch the output of subprocesses and redirect them to stdout while avoiding collisions that lead to unreadable output?

I am currently writing the output of the subprocesses to files (one per subprocess) but I'd rather have the output in stdout!

```
import argparse, sys, json
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

# Process parameters
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--cmd', type=str, help='command to be executed', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--pattern', type=str, help='pattern for the output files', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

# Create worker subprocesses and open output files
processes,files = [],[]
for i in range(cpu_count()):
    f = open(args.pattern.replace('{}',f'{i:02}'),'w')
    p = Popen(json.loads(args.cmd), stdout=f, stdin=PIPE)
    processes.append(p)
    files.append(f)

# Traiter le flux stdin
i = 0 # index of the next subprocess to feed with stdin
for line in sys.stdin:
    p = processes[i]
    p.stdin.write(line.encode())
    p.stdin.flush()
    i += 1
    if i==len(processes):
        i = 0

# Close output files
for i in range(cpu_count()):
    f = files[i]
    f.close()
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that you have, then we can help you troubleshoot the issues.

Comment: You could run them with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and capture stdout in Python, and only write it out when you get a newline. This sounds moderately challenging to pull off, though. If you are looking for a simple solution, GNU Parallel can do the input gathering for you.

Comment: I think I know how to deal with suprocesses as my implementation with files is working fine. The issue is that the subprocesses are continuously writing a lot of data to stdout (several MB/s). Redirecting all these data to the terminal (or a single file) show some "interlaced" output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shared resource problem. You have multiple processes vying for a shared resource (the screen). Unless you force synchronization, the text will garble.

I would recommend putting it into separate files like you've already done and if you want to see a live running output, do `tail -f *` on all the files in the directory with them.